# How can I write "#include" only once?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

In some large C++ projects, there are many `#include` directives. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

I have to write four `#include` in this example. I am so lazy that I only want to write it once. Perhaps like this:

```
#include {
    <iostream>
    <boost/asio.hpp>
    <boost/bind.hpp>
    <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
}
```

Is there any way to do it like this? Or can we define a macro to do this?

Comment: Personally, I just use "#in io" etc shortcuts that expand. Readable code, less typing, and works wherever I type it (including online compilers).

Comment: I would favour some form of IDE auto-completion, or some macros for your editor if you don't use an IDE.

Comment: @Petr Budnik, Copy/paste means duplicating. I think use `#include` only once may be more elegant.

Comment: In your second snippet you are duplicating whitespace and angular brackets!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, because #include uses preprocessor, and preprocessor is dumb as rock.

You could, however, write your own additional preprocessor that takes *.cpp file as input and converts your extended #include syntax into standard syntax. Example of preprocessor is [moc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/moc.html)

Or you could put all includes into single file, but that'll add unnecessary dependencies and in the long run will increase compilation times.

Personally, I wouldn't bother.

> Copy/paste means duplicating

Duplicating code (function bodies, for example) is bad. However, `#include` directive is not technically a code.

Comment: +1, I like the preprocessor idea. Copy-paste requires some discipline though: it is all to easy to copy a whole block of includes, leading to the same problems of the single include-all file.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think you people worry too much about include section. It is a very small part of the program (4..10..15 lines per file, maybe), and in most cases problems occur outside of it. In C++ programming, there are many other things to worry about.

Comment: Well, I really dislike unnecessary dependencies, but maybe that is just me being eccentric :)

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any way to do it like this?

No.

The best you could do is put all your `#include` directives into a dedicated header file, and then `#include` that single header everywhere it's needed.

Comment: And beware that this solution would most likely lead to all kinds of unnecessary include dependencies in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put all those in a file "files_to_be_included.h"

files_to_be_included.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

and then using

```
#include "files_to_be_included.h"
```

to include them all at once

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro that you *could* use (I wouldn't want to though, it made a nice little exercise on writing macros though):

```
#define HASH #
#define F(X) X

#define INCLUDE(X) F(HASH)include <X>

#define FEI_1(X, ...) INCLUDE(X)
#define FEI_2(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_3(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_4(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_5(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_6(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_5(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_7(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_6(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FEI_8(X, ...) INCLUDE(X) NEW_LINE FEI_7(__VA_ARGS__)

#define INCLUDE_BLOCK_(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,NAME,...) NAME
#define INCLUDE_BLOCK(...) INCLUDE_BLOCK_(__VA_ARGS__, \
    FEI_8,FEI_7,FEI_6,FEI_5,FEI_4,FEI_3,FEI_2,FEI_1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

If you stick this in a header file `header_header`, then you will be able to use it as follows:

```
#include <header_header>

INCLUDE_BLOCK(
    iostream,
    boost/asio.hpp,
    boost/bind.hpp,
    boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp)

/* Write Some Code Here */
```

This solution is not all that practical, in order to compile your code you now need to run the preprocessing stage twice and insert the `NEW_LINE` characters.

```
gcc -E main.cpp -o main.e.cpp
sed -i 's/NEW_LINE/\n/g' main.e.cpp
g++ main.e.cpp -o a.out
```

It would be possible to extend this code to create a specific `boost` include block that removes the need to keep adding the `boost` part.  One limit on this current implementation is that you can only include 8 headers.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDE/text editor have custom code snippets.
Check if you have a plug-in for your tool.